# Linear regression line in Swift using MLRegressor

Tags: swift, dataset, regression

I've been a little stuck with this challenge so decided to try and seek help here.

I am working on an iOS app in Swift. I draw charts with [Daniel Gindi's Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) (for context, irrelevant to my question).

I have the following dataset:

```
let data = [(key: -15.64, value: -2.90996446628), (key: -9.66, value: -0.42763685848), (key: -2.43, value: -2.593804963), (key: -2.188, value: -3.21188185361), (key: -0.65, value: -0.64038615264), (key: -0.63, value: 0.54083188026), (key: 1.07, value: -0.73129770794), (key: 1.12, value: -0.64902953727), (key: 1.27, value: -0.57766476054), (key: 2.57, value: 0.4391731834), (key: 2.77, value: -0.82565483197), (key: 16.32, value: -0.78957840951)]
```

It's a sorted set of key-value pairs from a data input that I receive from a server. At the moment I use that to create a scatter chart:

[image: Scatter chart]

Now, I would like to add a regression line. Apple displayed a sample on their [web page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/createml/mlregressor) that mentions MLRegressor. Specifically, this image:

[image: MLRegressor example]

However, I couldn't find a tutorial that would help me build my own linear regression line. What I really need is to generate an array of data points by/through the MLRegressor for each key-value pair in my data set. I can then build a line chart using this new array of data points and add it on top of my scatter chart.

Any help in using MLRegressor to generate an array of data would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After feeling discouraged by the first downvote I had to do a bit more search and here's what I've found (and implemented). There's a fantastic set of algorithms on [RayWenderlich's GitHub](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/tree/master/Linear%20Regression).

In addition, Paul Hudson of Hacking with Swift provides a good basic [intro to Create ML](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/145/how-to-perform-regression-analysis-using-create-ml).

Between the two of those resources, I achieved what I was looking for and the resulting predictions matched closely those manually created by my mentor (a Wall Street guy).

The code is actually rather short other than the method for displaying a mixed data graph. But there are good resources available for CombinedChartView as well.